# Multiple filter in multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with three columns `User_ID`, `order_status` and `Date`. `Order_status` is success or failure.

I need to find `User_ID` of those who have placed orders in Jan'21-Mar'21 and Jul'21-Sep'21 and not a successful order in Apr'21-Jun'21.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags (MySQL, SQL Server). Please tag only a single database.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use `EXCEPT` to find the *set difference* between two bags of rows:

```
select user_id 
from t
where order_status = 'success' and date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-03-31'
except 
select user_id 
from t
where order_status = 'failure' and date between '2021-07-01' and '2021-09-30'
```

Comment: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:0 missing EOF at 'except' near '"2021-03-31"'

Comment: @raghavbansal What database are you using? Works in SQL Server; see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb25662c878dabd7b8709706a621e8d2

Answer (score 0):

This statement should work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE order_status = 'failure' 
AND (date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-03-31' OR date BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-09-30')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [USER_ID]
,[ORDER_STATUS]
,[Date]
FROM [TBL_MAIN]
WHERE [Date] >= '2021-01-01' AND [Contract Date] < '2021-03-31'
AND ([ORDER_STATUS] = 'Success' AND [Date] >= '2021-04-01' AND [Contract Date] <       '2021-60-31')
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Duly noted @MarkRotteveel